# Scanning an octal and hexadecimal number in %d format specifier with scanf

Tags: c, hex, scanf, format-specifiers, octal

1. I was experimenting with the printing octal and hexadecimal number in C. The following is printing as expected

   ```
   int a = 012;
   printf("%d",a); //printing as 10. The decimal representation of octal 12.
   ```

   However, when I am scanning `012` using `%d` `0` is ignored and it is printing `12`. What is the reason?

   ```
   int b;
   scanf("%d",&b);
   printf("%d", b); //printing 12.
   ```
2. When I am scanning `0x12` using `%d` the output is giving as `0` as follows

   ```
   int b;
   scanf("%d",&b);
   printf("%d", b); //printing 0
   ```

What is the reason for this? Why they are not giving any runtime errors?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Re "*printing as 10. The octal of 12.*", This is incorrect. It prints 10, which is the *decimal* representation of *12 octal*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

```
int a = 012;    // a is assigned decimal value 10 (012 is octal = 10 in decimal)
printf("%d",a); // printing a in decimal as 10
```

In the case of first code snippet, you are assigning a=10 (which is represented as octal 012) and printing it in decimal format.

```
int b;
scanf("%d",&b);  // read an integer in decimal format
printf("%d", b); //printing 12 because the input was 12 after ignoring the 0.
```

When you're using scanf with %d, it expects an integer in decimal format. So it ignores the first 0 and assigns b = 12. And when you print it, you see 12.

```
int b;
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("%d", b); //printing 0
```

In the above case, you are asking scanf to read an integer in decimal format and when you enter 0x12, it stops scanning at character x after reading 0 since x cannot be a part of a valid integer.

**Solution**

So here is the way to go.

```
"%d" - to input decimal value
"%o" - to input integer value in an octal format
"%x" - to input integer value in hexadecimal format
"%i" - to input integer in any format (decimal/octal/hexadecimal)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` format specifier to `scanf` explicitly expects a number formatted as a decimal integer.  So when you enter "012" is reads 12 since the leading 0 is essentially ignored.  Then when you enter "0x12", the scanning stops at the character "x" so the value 0 is read.

If you use the `%i` format specifier, it will use hex if the string starts with "0x", octal if it starts with "0" and decimal otherwise.

Comment: *it will use hex if the string starts with "0x"*... more precisely: it will use hex if the string starts with `0x` followed by a hex digit, otherwise it will use octal and stop at the `x`.